# How to find by Selenium a tag that's produced by javascript (I guess)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Heyo!

I have to download a file from corporate site by using Selenium, and got stucked on the last step:

When I press Ctrl+U on the site the code contains only base tags like   and some s those are empty:

```
<div ng-show="viewContainer === 'PUC'" 
    class="ng-app-element deny-animation-change" animate="fade" 
    id="pucWrapper" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

    <div id="pucHeader" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <div id="pucMenuBar"></div>
      <div id="pucPerspectives"></div>
      <div id="pucToolBar"></div>
      <div id="pucUserDropDown"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="pucContent"></div>
  </div>
```

but when i select and inspect an element by Chrome dev tool 
it says that there are many tags in `<div id="pucContent">`, how to find an "invisible" `<select>` tag by Selenium?

The code below returns with `NoSuchElementException`

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'pucContent'))).find_element_by_tag_name('select')
```

My guess that javascript creates new tags and all content within `<div id="pucContent">` tag

Comment: If Selenium doesn't find the tag when you search for it, then it's not there. With the caveats that 1. what you _search for_ is not there, hence you could be searching for something wrong 2. it's not there _when you're searching_ hence you could be searching for the correct thing before it's been added or after it's been removed.

Comment: Paste the HTML that is displayed after the page is loaded and using Inspect with the dev toolbar. It will give you a better idea of what the page looks like when you need to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `<div id="pucContent"></div>` is there at the beginning and gets populated after the page is loaded. So what you really need to be waiting for in your wait is something inside that. If there is a `<select>` inside that elemeint when you inspect, try waiting like this:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#pucContent select'))).find_element_by_tag_name('select')
```

Keep in mind the "page_source" of a web page is only what is passed when the document is requested, it won't contain anything loaded dynamically after the original document is loaded.